# Increase tumblr photo size

Tags: html, image, photo, tumblr, css

How do I edit this html so I can customize the width of a photo, tumblr doesn't seem to like changing the photo set size to anything bigger. I have looked up, but don't understand where a `maxwidth:600px` would fit in or if this is even the best way to do it.

Massive thanks to anyone who can help me out

```
{block:Photo}

  <div class="permalink">
    {block:IfNotDisqusShortname}<a href="{Permalink}">&rarr;</a>{block:IfNotDisqusShortname}
    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
  </div>

  <div class="photo post">

    {LinkOpenTag}
      <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
    {LinkCloseTag}

    {block:Caption}
      <p>{Caption}</p>
    {/block:Caption}

    <div class="postmeta">{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>&nbsp; {/block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}" style="text-transform:lowercase;">{lang:Notes} ({NoteCount})</a></div>

  </div>

  {block:PostNotes}
    <div>{PostNotes}</div>
  {/block:PostNotes}

{/block:Photo}
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether your trying to alter the appearance of a photo (one image) or a photoset (multiple images) post. Tumblr handles both different, thus the answer will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Enlarging from `500px` makes it blurrier. Tumblr does actually store a copy of your image wider than `500px`. It's called `HighRes`, and it's (up to) `1280px`.

In your theme HTML, Replace `photoURL-500` with `photo-HighRes`, for example, and resize from that.

In my theme, I use it like so:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}<a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">{/block:PermalinkPage}
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" {block:IndexPage}width="435px"
{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}width="900px"{/block:PermalinkPage}/>
```

It shrinks the 1280px down to 435px for the index and shrinks it to 900px for the permalink page, as seen here: http://phillypraxis.tumblr.com/tagged/images

Comment: Whilst this will give you the desired effect, your sending a 1280px wide image to do the job of a 500px image.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could simply add width="600" before the alt attribute of the image tag:

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="600" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
```

Comment: @Philip I've added the code. I didn't do it before because I was on a mobile device.

Answer (score -1):

Check on the slidestheme.tumblr.com, on the source code for this line:

```
enter code herereplaceRawPhotoLinks: function() {
      $("article.photo div.media a[href*='/photo/1280']").each(function() {`enter code here`
```

Comment: Code is incomplete and zero explanation as to what this actual does.