# How can I change the default forced 500 in tumblr's URL for photos?

Tags: html, css, width, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I know it has already been asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967111/increase-tumblr-photo-size) but the solution doesn't work for me.

> Enlarging from 500px makes it blurrier. Tumblr does actually store a
>   copy of your image wider than 500px. It's called HighRes, and it's (up
>   to) 1280px.
>
> In your theme HTML, Replace photoURL-500 with photo-HighRes, for
>   example, and resize from that.

As you can see from my tumblr page (http://reviewsbytea.tumblr.com/) the image url has "500" in it and it stretches and looks ugly even though [in the code](http://puu.sh/klk5f/4336ad3022.png) it's clearly written:

[image]

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"/>
```

I tried {PhotoURL-100}, I tried {PhotoURL-1280}. Nothing changes! The generated URL still has 500 in it.

Help please?

Comment: Are you using - or _ ? I used _1280 and it worked for me.

Comment: <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/47c43e926ea44fb5191f8934a33a8b1b/tumblr_inline_nv4sx7qyPR1tbjrsq_1280.jpg"

Comment: Yes, I know how to manually get the desired resolution using underline. I want the tumblr function thingy to generate it for me. Tumblr fails to properly generate the URL.

Comment: I checked the source code of the link you provided. the code doesn't look like the image you attached here. Check your code, additionally, the post type for the post on the blog is text, not a photo :)

Answer (score 0):

Adam Azad in the comments was right: the issue was that I was editing {block:Photo} (for photo posts) instead of {block:Text} that I was using.

It seems it is not possible to use the  at all in a text post. It defaults to 500px width anyway.

Comment: If you want images in `Text` post body, or in `captions` etc to be more than "500px" wide, use `{block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="1280"}` instead of `{block:Posts}`, for example. Just note that you will see higher resolution image, only when it is available.